# How to use stata for linear regression

Tags: regression, stata

```
      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =    1797
-------------+------------------------------           F(  1,  1795) =  815.71
       Model |  273.788275     1  273.788275           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  602.478503  1795   .33564262           R-squared     =  0.3124
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.3121
       Total |  876.266777  1796  .487899097           Root MSE      =  .57935

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   no_claims |  -.1914365   .0067028   -28.56   0.000    -.2045826   -.1782904
       _cons |  -1.960553   .0306965   -63.87   0.000    -2.020758   -1.900348
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I got the above data by typing `regress y no_claims`. Y is model by Y = $\alpha$ + $\beta x$ + $R$. But I am not sure where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is represented in the above table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are asking for the regression *coefficients*, which are represented in the `Coef.` column in your table. The coefficient for the intercept for your model, $\alpha$, is contained in the row labeled as `_cons`, an abbreviation for constant. The other row in the current table represents the information associated with the `no_claims` term in the model.

The lingo may change slightly between different statistical packages, but the abbreviations in the above table are pretty standard for any linear regression output. Any introduction textbook on statistics covers all of the information presented in the above table.

Comment: Sorry if I sound curt for suggesting an introduction to statistics textbook, but it is hard to imagine such confusion arising from anything other than lacking any reasonable introduction to OLS (such as non-familiarity with English).

Comment: Do you know which variables above represent $S_{xy}$, $S_{xx}$, y^bar, x^bar?

Comment: @Mark, I do not know what you are referring to when you say $S_{xy}$ or $S_{xx}$. If `y^bar` and `x^bar` refer to the estimate of the mean for either `no_claims` or `y` in your comment then they are not directly contained in the regression equation. What exactly is your goal in computing the regression equation (it doesn't seem you are particularly interested in interpreting the equation)?